# Sound has randomly stopped working on my laptop

Tags: audio, speakers

I have a Dell Vostro 3500 laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium. I put it on sleep earlier, but after booting it up again, I found that the sound is now longer working, either through the built in speakers or the headphones...

I have checked all of the settings that I can think, and nothing is any different to how it was prior to when I put the laptop on sleep, when the sound was working...

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Checklist of sorts. Needed to be put here since I cannot comment.

- Have you unplugged everything from the audio port(s)? *If not, do so.*
- Have you recently installed any new software? *If so, what was it? You may need to reverse the aforementioned installation.*
- Be sure you have your sound output (in the sound settings) set to the appropriate device(s).

Comment: Yes, I have unplugged everything from the audio ports, I have not recently installed any new software and the playback is set to "speakers/ headphones" in the sound settings... 

I have not changed any of the sound settings since when it was last working, so nothing should have changed...

Comment: Ok, no worries, restarting the computer seemed to sort it... just really random that it stopped working